# Python: Is there any way of writing in an output file waiting some seconds before writing the next line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In order to graph a file which I'm constantly writing in, it's necessary to make some pauses between each line that the code writes in the output file. If not, the file becomes a heavy file and python have troubles graphing it.

I've already tried with the time.sleep() with any result but having the line I want to write as example just once in the file.

```
Escribir = True

my_file = open("testwrite.txt", "w")

while Escribir:

    my_file.write("hola" + "\n")
    time.sleep(2)
my_file.close
```

I expect the output of 
Hola

Hola

Hola

With a new line every 2 seconds, but instead I get an Hola just once.

Have a nice day, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very likely that you don't see new "hola" in the file because it hasn't been flushed to the file from the buffer. To make sure it is flushed before continuing, use `flush()`

```
Escribir = True

my_file = open("testwrite.txt", "w")

while Escribir:

    my_file.write("hola" + "\n")
    my_file.flush()
    time.sleep(2)
my_file.close()
```

Comment: Effectively, it was the problem. It was so useful.